# How to install with pacman in ArchLinux without asking the user y/n?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I am looking for the equivalent of RHEL's `yum -y` in ArchLinux's `pacman` so that I can install packages with a shell script without asking the user questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The option you are looking for is `--noconfirm` . It is available in pacman's 8 man page and is [also available here](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html#_options)

however, it is best to avoid using it and is highly recommended to always read and understand pacman's output.